# AspectJ exchange data between Advice and JoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am looking for a way to pass objects between Advice and JoinPoint, something like the following,

```
@Aspect
class SomeAspect {

    @Around(execution * *.*(..) && @annotation(sample))
    public Object PassbyRef(PJP pjp) {

        SomeObjectToPass someObj = new SomeObjecttoPass();

        Object retVal = pjp.proceed(someObj);
        //process(someObj);
    }
}

class UsingAspect {

    @sample
    public Object TestMethod() {

        //how do I access someObj in this method?
    }
}
```

I am looking to perform some action before execution of a method/JP, then I need to way to communicate between advice and method being executed, then I need to perform more actions after method has been executed.

Comment: This is not a good idea. The advised code should not know about the advice.

Comment: Look into `ThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange idea but if your design requires this You can try something like that:

just add a getter to your Advice class or maybe create an interface that requires this

```
class UsingAspect {
public getSomeObj(){return someObj};
}
```

and then from Aspect

```
if (joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() == UsingAspect.class){
  UsingAspect ua=(UsingAspect)joinpoint.getTarget();
  ua.getSomeObj()
}
```

Then in Advice and Aspect you should have reference to the same someObj. If you would like to do this in reverse direction just add a setter and save an object to your Advice class.